# How to find if the local computer is in a domain?

Tags: powershell

Is there an easy and **fast** way to find out if the local computer is joined to a domain with PowerShell?

I find lots of stuff about getting the current workgroup OR domain but no clear indications on how to know if it really is a workgroup or domain. Just want to find this out before calling some Active Directory related stuff that only gives a timeout after a long wait on workgroup computers.

The `[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()` method takes a long time before failing on workgroup computers and the WMI class `Win32_ComputerSystem` shows the name but not if it is a real domain.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`Win32_ComputerSystem` has a `PartOfDomain` property that indicates whether the computer is domain joined or not. There is also a workgroup property - that should be blank if the computer is on a domain.

Example:

```
if ((gwmi win32_computersystem).partofdomain -eq $true) {
    write-host -fore green "I am domain joined!"
} else {
    write-host -fore red "Ooops, workgroup!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe type 'Systeminfo' in PowerShell and look under 'Domain' ?

Comment: I mean you can but there are many better ways to get this programmatically in PowerShell than parsing the output of `systeminfo`.

Answer (score -2):

This is simple.  Works because if a computer is not in a domain, the default userdomain is the local computer

```
if ($env:computername  -eq $env:userdomain) { echo " no AD domain" } 
else { echo "must be in AD"}
```

Comment: This does not work if the user logs in using a local account or is a built-in system account. This will also fail in a multi-domain environment when the user and computer are not in the same domain.