# How to find if a list of computers on are a domain using Powershell?

Tags: list, powershell, dns, ip

I need to check a list (.txt) of IP's (or hostnames) to find if they are domain connected or not and perform a task accordingly. I found this post here ([How to find if the local computer is in a domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409043/how-to-find-if-the-local-computer-is-in-a-domain)) which is almost exactly what I'm after except it does it for the local machine. I tried to modify the script to suit but I don't have much experience with PowerShell.

If anyone is able to help it would be much appreciated.
Cheers
David

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code with -Computername parameter and provide explicit credentials in case the remote computer administrator credentials are different from what you are using.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$servers = Get-Content C:\scripts\Servers.txt 
Foreach ($server in $servers) {
    if ((gwmi win32_computersystem -computername $server -Credential $cred).partofdomain -eq $true) {
        #Do something Here
    } else {
        #Do something Here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of valis server names, you could check if they have a corresponding computer account in AD:

```
Get-Content .\Servers.txt | Foreah-Object {

    if(Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $_})
    {
        "machine $_ is a part of default domain"
    }
    else
    {
        "machine $_ IS NOT a part of default domain"    
    }

}
```